# sqlite query problem in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

hi
 how can i include NSString in the following query.House is as NSString.If i give
like following directly, it works fine.but i want to execute through NSString.

```
 NSString* str = @"House";

 const char *sqlStatement = "select rowid from PlaceTable where name = 'MyUncleHouse'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSString's method called UTF8String as follows:

```
NSString *str = ["SELECT rowid from PlaceTable where name = '" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@'",my_uncle_house_str];

const char *sql_statement = [str UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

NSString* str = @"MyUncleHouse";

NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select rowid from PlaceTable where name = '%@',str];

const char *sql_statement = [str UTF8String];